# How to connect Mongo Atlas Database in Lambda function with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, lambda, serverless-framework

I am using Serverless framework to deploy my backend to API Gateway and AWS Lambda.

Here is my serverless.yml for this specific lambda function. 
It is a cron job that runs every hour.

```
 cron:
     handler: handler.transferHandler
     events:
     - schedule: rate(1 hour)
```

Now when I test on localhost it works perfectly. But when I deploy to aws I get the following error:

```
    MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDb is running. { MongoError: failed to connect to server [undefined:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:189:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1021:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [undefined:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017]' }
```

Here is my function in my `handler.js`:

```
exports.transferHandler = function transferHandler(event, context) {

  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  mongoose.connect(mongoString, {useMongoClient: true});
  const db = mongoose.connection;

  db.on("error", (err) => {
     console.log("MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDb is running.", err);
     process.exit();
  });

  db.once('open', () => {
      BookingModel
          .find({})
          .then((bookings) => {
            ...
          })
          .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
          })
          .finally(() => {
            db.close();
          });
    });
};
```

Comment: Is mongod running in your AWS server? Also useMongoClient is deprecated in mongoose 5.

Comment: @LeekInPajama I am using mongoose 4.13.9, and I have not seen anything about needing mongod running. Can you explain?

Comment: the `mongod` service should be running on your server background. To check MongoDB is running or not, simply type `mongo`  in (remote) command line. If you're running MongoDB from AWS.  I strongly suggest you always use lastest mongoose. If you google **mongoose vulnerabilities**, this thing is very vulnerable.

Comment: @LeekInPajama i am using mongo atlas for my database and my mongo string is the mongo connection string provided by mongo atlas, only thing i am hosting on aws is my lambda functions and static files on s3.

Comment: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/getting-started/#configure-ip-whitelisting-to-grant-access-to-your-cluster Is this helpful?

Comment: @LeekInPajama i am connecting fine locally (so my local host is connecting to my hosted mongo database in atlas). this issue is happening once I deploy and try to connect my api to my data. ive already whitelisted 0.0.0.0 to my development database.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 weeks of being stuck on this, I learned that I needed to specify my environment variables in my `serverless.yml` for it to work. My functions were never connecting to the database because my mongo string was never set in lambda. Hope this helps someone.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: production
  region: us-west-1
  environment:
    MONGODB_URL: ${env:MONGODB_URL}
    S3_BUCKET: ${env:S3_BUCKET}
    S3_BUCKET_REPORT: ${env:S3_BUCKET_REPORT}
    STRIPE_CLIENT_ID: ${env:STRIPE_CLIENT_ID}
    STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: ${env:STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}
    STRIPE_SECERET_KEY: ${env:STRIPE_SECERET_KEY}
    JWT_SECRET: ${env:JWT_SECRET}
    SEND_BIRD_TOKEN: ${env:SEND_BIRD_TOKEN}
    SEND_BIRD_APP_ID: ${env:SEND_BIRD_APP_ID}
    MANDRILL_APIKEY: ${env:MANDRILL_APIKEY}
```